# Обнуление поля при наличии в другом поля определенного значения

Tags: mysql

Есть такая табличка (типы пока не значат ничего):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Эта табличка призвана хранить различные задачи таких категорий, как встреча, выполнить, звонок, письменная работа.
Нет проблем с остальными, но столкнулся с тем, что нужно ограничить возможность заполнения поля `call direction`, если была выбрана `category` отличная от звонка.
Какими средствами это можно сделать в mysql?

Comment: чем там у вас мотивирован выбор `tinyint` для первичного и `varchar` для внешних ключей? Ограничить заполнение вы можете либо в логике вашего ПО, либо с помощью триггера в БД для добавления/редактирования.

Comment: @teran >>>>>>>>>>>типы пока не значат ничего<<<<<<<<<<<<  Они там все варчар 255 как бы.

Comment: @teran спасибо, так и думал, что в триггеры придется влезать